# Equivalent code in C# for this code in C++

Tags: c#-4.0, memory-management, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am new to working in C#, so might seem simple to many of you, but I need help here.
I have to create a desktop application in c# that gets connected to a  Bluetooth low energy device and send values to the device using [Set characteristic value function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh450806%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). For this I need to get Characteristic buffer using [get characteristics function.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh450795%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

I have C++ code to do this:

```
USHORT charBufferSize  = 0;
HRESULT hres = BluetoothGATTGetCharacteristics( BLE_Service,NULL, 0,NULL,
                                                 &charBufferSize,BLUETOOTH_GATT_FLAG_NONE);

 if(hres==HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_MORE_DATA)) 
   {
      Characteristic_Buffer = new BTH_LE_GATT_CHARACTERISTIC [charBufferSize ];                                                       
   }                                                       
USHORT val = 0;
// get characteristics after allocating required size 
hres = BluetoothGATTGetCharacteristics(BLE_Service,NULL,charBufferSize,
                                 Characteristic_Buffer,&val,BLUETOOTH_GATT_FLAG_NONE);
```

I have to do samething in C#
So I tried something like this

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public struct BTH_LE_GATT_CHARACTERISTIC
    {
        public UInt16 ServiceHandle;
        public BTH_LE_UUID CharacteristicUuid;
        public UInt16 AttributeHandle;
        public UInt16 CharacteristicValueHandle;
        public Boolean IsBroadcastable;
        public Boolean IsReadable;
        public Boolean IsWritable;
        public Boolean IsWritableWithoutResponse;
        public Boolean IsSignedWritable;
        public Boolean IsNotifiable;
        public Boolean IsIndicatable;
        public Boolean HasExtendedProperties;
    } 

[DllImport(@"BluetoothApis.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]

public static extern Boolean BluetoothGATTGetCharacteristics(
                                                         IntPtr Device_Handle,
                                                         IntPtr Service,
                                                         UInt16 Char_Buffer_Count,
                                     ref BTH_LE_GATT_CHARACTERISTIC CharBuffer,
                                                         out UInt16 RequiredSize,
                                                         uint Flags
                                                         );
UInt16 Size_Required = 0;
UInt16 NBytes = 0;
BTH_LE_GATT_CHARACTERISTIC gattChar = new BTH_LE_GATT_CHARACTERISTIC();


Success = BluetoothGATTGetCharacteristics(Ble_Device, IntPtr.Zero, 0, IntPtr.Zero, 
                  out Size_Required, (uint)BTH_LE_FLAGS.BLUETOOTH_GATT_FLAG_NONE);
```

I am stuck here. Now, to make second call to the function, I should allocate memory to the characteristic buffer as done in C++

Any suggestions as how to do this or Is there any other way to get the Characteristic buffer in C#??

Thanks in advance